# Turn on ADB remotely via USB

Tags: android, debugging, adb

I'am trying to automate some tests and for that I need to launch some ADB commands. The problem is that I need to do a Factory Data Reset during the tests, and after that the USB Debugging option is disabled.
Do you guys know a way to turn it on without touching the device?

Answer (score 1):

When your development process has progressed to the point of using automated tests - it's a good idea to start using a dedicated development device for testing - the one with an unlocked bootloader and a development Android build loaded.

You can customize such device so it would have `USB Debugging` enabled by default after `FDR` and even have your public RSA key preloaded (so your PC will be automatically authenticated by your device).

Answer (score 0):

For obvious security reasons, you can't force-enable USB Debugging on a device.
Plus, if there were a "command" to enable USB Debugging, it would require USB Debugging to be executed.