# Keeping USB Debugging on even after factory reset, also bypassing RSA Keys

Tags: android, debugging, kernel, usb, reset

I have a **Nexus 10** and I'm running some code to automate the tablet. I need USB Debugging to stay ON and obviously without the RSA key pop up. I have modified my `build.prop` and `default.prop` and i got USB debugging to still be on after reset. But I can not find how to get around the RSA Key pop up. You must press the RSA Key to make usb debugging authorized, otherwise it unauthorized.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27658803/1778421

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44817341/1778421

Answer (score 1):

Just copy android RSA KEYS for all the devices that you allow access and save it. And add all of them to the devices adb_keys.pub file. Create a backup for it that way every time restore it has them saved. Or just every time overwrite the devices is adb_keys file. It wont prompt the message on any of the device keys you added.